# Regular Expression to validate values below 170000

Tags: regex, validation

HI I have a  small validation to check if values are below 170000,
Here is what i have tried but it has some small issues. values can range from 0 - 170000

/^(?:[1-9]\d{0,4}|[1-6]\d{3}|170000)$/

Please some one rectify and explain this.

Comment: Why not cast it into a number?

Comment: What language/tool are you trying to target?

Comment: i am using extjs text field validation, my field has masking proerty from extjs, hence i need to test validation using RegExp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need regex for that?

Can't `if (value <= 170000 && value >= 0)` achieve your job?

Comment: I think the OP wants below 170000, not including

Comment: @musefan Check the regex he gives, it include `170000`

Comment: Yeah I see that, but that does not mean that is not one of the problems with the Regex. Of course, this is quite obvious so perhaps that is a good indicator that it is meant to be inclusive, but then again I try not to assume any level of intelligence from peoples questions

Comment: hi i am using it with ExtJS, I have few masking also for this field. hence i am using RegExp. valid values needs to be in range 0-170000

Comment: @PunithRaj You still don't need to use regex. Just check the the input is number and the number is in range.

Comment: @xdazz ,  thanks it was pretty easy, tought i need to use RegExp here.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^\D*(\d{1,5}|1[0-6]\d{4}|170000)\D*$/
```

This will check the entire string. Otherwise, you need to fine-tune the regex boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
\b(\d{1,5})\b|\b([1][0123456]\d{4})\b|\b(170000)\b
```

Demo :
http://regexr.com?328t5

Explained:

1. `\b(\d{1,5})\b` : Match  all numbers from 0 to 99999
2. `\b([1][0123456]\d{3})\b` : Match 1 followed by 0 to 6, followed by any 4 digits i.e. 100000 to 169999
3. `\b(170000)\b` : Match 170000

Comment: Missed a zero: should be 170000

Answer (score 1):

Though using regexes for range validation is best avoided if possible, I think your problem lies with the second of your regex segments:

- `[1-9]\d{0,4}`
- `[1-6]\d{3}`
- `170000`

The first will handle all numbers with lengths 1 thru 5 inclusive and the second should therefore handle six-digit numbers from `100000` up to (but not including) `170000` (which is handled by the third segment).

However, it's only handling four-digit numbers (which are already handled by the first segment anyway) so I suspect it should actually be `1[0-6]\d{4}`.

In other words, `/^(?:[1-9]\d{0,4}|1[0-6]\d{4}|170000)$/`.

Comment: You are forgetting it also needs to handle the leading 1. Plus of course it needs to handle zeros

Answer (score 0):

This solved it, was pretty easy and solved without RegExp :)
Others who posted RegExp for validation thanks to them too.

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
    //  vtype validation function
    msrp: function(val, field) {
        if(val >= 0 && val <= 170000){
            return true;                
        }else{
            return bundle.getMsg('vl.locate.label.ntavalidmsrp');
        }
        return validMaxMSRPTest.test(val);
    },
    // vtype Text property: The error text to display when the validation function returns false
    msrpText: bundle.getMsg('vl.locate.label.ntavalidmsrp')
});
```